New Relic Node.js Agent Reporting When Running The Function App Locally but Doesn't Report When Running on Azure
I have a Function App and I have added the newrelic.js file on the directory
    'use strict';
exports.config = {
  app_name: ['app-name'],
  license_key: process.env.NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY,
  agent_enabled: true,
  allow_all_headers: true,
  attributes: {
    exclude: [
      'request.headers.cookie',
      'request.headers.authorization',
      'request.headers.proxyAuthorization',
      'request.headers.setCookie*',
      'request.headers.x*',
      'response.headers.cookie',
      'response.headers.authorization',
      'response.headers.proxyAuthorization',
      'response.headers.setCookie*',
      'response.headers.x*'
    ]
  },
  application_logging: {
    forwarding: {
      enabled: true,
      max_samples_stored: 10000
    }
  }
};

I have a custom logger defined like this
const newrelic = require('newrelic');

const logger = {
  info: (message: string) => {
    newrelic.recordLogEvent({
      message: message,
      level: 'info'
    });
  },
  warn: (message: string) => {
    newrelic.recordLogEvent({
      message: message,
      level: 'warn'
    });
  },
  error: (message: string) => {
    newrelic.recordLogEvent({
      message: message,
      level: 'error'
    });
  }
};

export { logger };

I am importing this logged in my index.ts file for the function app so I can run logger.info, logger.error etc. When I func start and run the function app locally it works perfectly but when I deploy the app to Azure and run it from there I don't see any logs. The Function app seems to detect blob though when I check the log stream.
